# pull access denied for container-registry.oracle.com/database/enterprise

Tags: oracle, docker, container-registry

I have been trying to pull a docker image: container-`registry.oracle.com/database/enterprise:12.2.0.1`

but i am getting the following error ::

> Error response from daemon: pull access denied for
>   container-registry.oracle.com/database/enterprise, repository does not
>   exist or may require 'docker login'

I even tried logging in to the oracle repository. But the outcome is no different.

```
root@Linux-Vostro-3250:~# docker pull container-registry.oracle.com/database/enterprise:12.2.0.1

Error response from daemon: pull access denied for container-registry.oracle.com/database/enterprise, repository does not exist or may require 'docker login'
root@Linux-Vostro-3250:~# 
root@Linux-Vostro-3250:~# docker login container-registry.oracle.com
Username (amal.v@ctebs.com): amal.v@ctebs.com
Password: 
Login Succeeded
root@Linux-Vostro-3250:~# docker pull container-registry.oracle.com/database/enterprise:12.2.0.1
Error response from daemon: pull access denied for container-registry.oracle.com/database/enterprise, repository does not exist or may require 'docker login'
root@Linux-Vostro-3250:~#
```

I also tried to pull the same image from docker store by logging in.

Hoping for an explanation..Thanks for your time !!

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Probably you need to login to oracle repository and accept licence terms. Sign in on https://container-registry.oracle.com and then go to Database -> enterprise links. You should be asked to accept licence terms and finally land on an "Oracle Database Server 12.2.0.1 Docker Image Documentation" page. Then you should be able to pull the image.

Comment: If you're trying other softwares (like kubernetes) you need also enable it on registry.

Comment: You can also register on https://hub.docker.com/_/oracle-database-enterprise-edition

Comment: After accepting the license, follow [@Sara_Jahanzad answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56245554/196507) (execute `docker login ...`)

Answer (score 24):

The initial solution did not work for me, but this did:
In your command line run:

```
docker login container-registry.oracle.com
```

Enter in your Oracle credentials, then run your original command again!

Comment: You need to accept the license, follow [@amorfis answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47887936/196507) before executing the `docker login` command.

Answer (score 10):

windows 10, desktop docker ver2.0.0.3
**steps to pull oracle database-enterprise:12.2.0.1:**

1. log into https://hub.docker.com/
2. search "oracle database"
3. click on "Oracle Database Enterprise Edition"
4. click on "Proceed to Checkout"
5. fill in your contact info on the left, check two boxes under "Developer Tier" on the right, click on "Get Content"
6. under "Resources", click double-box icon (will copy "docker pull ..." to your clipboard)
7. go back to your windows command line
   type "docker login", 
   type your docker hub login and password
8. paste the command on your clipboard
   "docker pull store/oracle/database-enterprise:12:2.0.1"

Comment: This method no longer works. Follow  [@F_Usman explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58302841/196507).

Answer (score 3):

You have to login into Oracle's registry by using the command:

```
docker login container-registry.oracle.com
```

and then pull the desirable image.

**If the error is still available** be sure that you *accept the terms and conditions* in Oracle Registry. For example:
[image]

Answer (score 2):

--Starting an Oracle Database Server instance
First Open in browser : https://container-registry.oracle.com
Click Sigin: Enter user/password (if do not have then create new one)
Click on Database->enterprise (continue -> Go down and accept the licence.)
Now com to the docker to login:
docker login https://container-registry.oracle.com
User:user/pswd
docker run -d --name usman-oracle store/oracle/database-enterprise:12.2.0.1
OR: $ docker run -d -it --name usman-oracle container-registry.oracle.com/database/enterprise:12.2.0.1