# Oracle 12c docker setup on Apple M1

Tags: oracle, docker, oracle12c, apple-m1

I am trying to run Oracle db in docker on M1 Mac. I have tried images from both `store/oracle/database-enterprise:12.2.0.1-slim` and `container-registry.oracle.com/database/enterprise:12.2.0.1-slim` but getting the same error.

`docker run -d -it --name oracle -v $(pwd)/db/oradata:/ORCL store/oracle/database-enterprise:12.2.0.1-slim`

I also tried non-slim version and by providing the `--platform linux/amd64` to the docker command. Result is same.

Here's the result of `docker logs -f oracle`

```sh
Setup Oracle Database
Oracle Database 12.2.0.1 Setup
Sat Jul 31 18:44:14 UTC 2021

Check parameters ......
log file is : /home/oracle/setup/log/paramChk.log
paramChk.sh is done at 1 sec

untar DB bits ......
log file is : /home/oracle/setup/log/untarDB.log
untarDB.sh is done at 29 sec

config DB ......
log file is : /home/oracle/setup/log/configDB.log
Sat Jul 31 18:44:42 UTC 2021
Start Docker DB configuration
Call configDBora.sh to configure database
Sat Jul 31 18:44:42 UTC 2021
Configure DB as oracle user
Setup Database directories ...

SQL*Plus: Release 12.2.0.1.0 Production on Sat Jul 31 18:44:43 2021

Copyright (c) 1982, 2016, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

ERROR:
ORA-12547: TNS:lost contact


Enter user-name: SP2-0306: Invalid option.
Usage: CONN[ECT] [{logon|/|proxy} [AS {SYSDBA|SYSOPER|SYSASM|SYSBACKUP|SYSDG|SYSKM|SYSRAC}] [edition=value]]
where <logon> ::= <username>[/<password>][@<connect_identifier>]
      <proxy> ::= <proxyuser>[<username>][/<password>][@<connect_identifier>]
Enter user-name: Enter password: 
ERROR:
ORA-12547: TNS:lost contact


SP2-0157: unable to CONNECT to ORACLE after 3 attempts, exiting SQL*Plus
update password

Enter password for SYS: 
create pdb : ORCLPDB1

SQL*Plus: Release 12.2.0.1.0 Production on Sat Jul 31 18:44:43 2021

Copyright (c) 1982, 2016, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

ERROR:
ORA-12547: TNS:lost contact


Enter user-name: SP2-0306: Invalid option.
Usage: CONN[ECT] [{logon|/|proxy} [AS {SYSDBA|SYSOPER|SYSASM|SYSBACKUP|SYSDG|SYSKM|SYSRAC}] [edition=value]]
where <logon> ::= <username>[/<password>][@<connect_identifier>]
      <proxy> ::= <proxyuser>[<username>][/<password>][@<connect_identifier>]
Enter user-name: SP2-0306: Invalid option.
Usage: CONN[ECT] [{logon|/|proxy} [AS {SYSDBA|SYSOPER|SYSASM|SYSBACKUP|SYSDG|SYSKM|SYSRAC}] [edition=value]]
where <logon> ::= <username>[/<password>][@<connect_identifier>]
      <proxy> ::= <proxyuser>[<username>][/<password>][@<connect_identifier>]
SP2-0157: unable to CONNECT to ORACLE after 3 attempts, exiting SQL*Plus
Reset Database parameters

SQL*Plus: Release 12.2.0.1.0 Production on Sat Jul 31 18:44:43 2021

Copyright (c) 1982, 2016, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

ERROR:
ORA-12547: TNS:lost contact


Enter user-name: SP2-0306: Invalid option.
Usage: CONN[ECT] [{logon|/|proxy} [AS {SYSDBA|SYSOPER|SYSASM|SYSBACKUP|SYSDG|SYSKM|SYSRAC}] [edition=value]]
where <logon> ::= <username>[/<password>][@<connect_identifier>]
      <proxy> ::= <proxyuser>[<username>][/<password>][@<connect_identifier>]
Enter user-name: Enter password: 
ERROR:
ORA-12547: TNS:lost contact


SP2-0157: unable to CONNECT to ORACLE after 3 attempts, exiting SQL*Plus

LSNRCTL for Linux: Version 12.2.0.1.0 - Production on 31-JUL-2021 18:44:44

Copyright (c) 1991, 2016, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Starting /u01/app/oracle/product/12.2.0/dbhome_1/bin/tnslsnr: please wait...

TNSLSNR for Linux: Version 12.2.0.1.0 - Production
System parameter file is /u01/app/oracle/product/12.2.0/dbhome_1/admin/ORCLCDB/listener.ora
Log messages written to /u01/app/oracle/diag/tnslsnr/989db909d8df/listener/alert/log.xml
Listening on: (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=0.0.0.0)(PORT=1521)))
Listening on: (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=ipc)(KEY=EXTPROC1521)))

Connecting to (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=0.0.0.0)(PORT=1521)))
STATUS of the LISTENER
------------------------
Alias                     LISTENER
Version                   TNSLSNR for Linux: Version 12.2.0.1.0 - Production
Start Date                31-JUL-2021 18:44:44
Uptime                    0 days 0 hr. 0 min. 0 sec
Trace Level               off
Security                  ON: Local OS Authentication
SNMP                      OFF
Listener Parameter File   /u01/app/oracle/product/12.2.0/dbhome_1/admin/ORCLCDB/listener.ora
Listener Log File         /u01/app/oracle/diag/tnslsnr/989db909d8df/listener/alert/log.xml
Listening Endpoints Summary...
  (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=0.0.0.0)(PORT=1521)))
  (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=ipc)(KEY=EXTPROC1521)))
The listener supports no services
The command completed successfully

DONE!
Remove password info
Docker DB configuration is complete !
ERROR : config DB failed, please check log /home/oracle/setup/log/configDB.log for details!
OS process OFSD (ospid 188) idle for 30 seconds, exiting
2017-08-09T10:36:20.752530+00:00
ARCH: Archival disabled due to shutdown: 1090
Shutting down archive processes
Archiving is disabled
JIT: pid 563 requesting stop
2017-08-09T10:36:20.815635+00:00
Stopping background process VKTM
2017-08-09T10:36:26.581058+00:00
Instance shutdown complete (OS id: 563)
/usr/bin/tail: inotify cannot be used, reverting to polling: Function not implemented
```

Is it the issue with M1 or I my configuration

Comment: Oracle server does not support Mac OS as the underlying operating system. The recommended approach is to use Oracle VM VirtualBox (which _does_ run on Mac) and create an Oracle Linux VM and run the database on that. Even if you do get it to run on Mac natively (as I understand some claim to have done), the results will not be predictable and you will not be able to get support for the configuration.

Comment: This is supported by the error message you posted: `ERROR : config DB failed, please check log /home/oracle/setup/log/configDB.log for details!` which indicates that the database failed to configure itself correctly when it was created and will not startup.

Comment: Thanks @pmdba. yeah I later on found an issue on Github where they explicitly mentioned that the docker images don't support M1 right now. 
And to add to what you said about VirtualBox is that they are also not supported on M1 chips. So the only way right now is to either use Parallels for running Windows 10 and then run Oracle in it or start using my old Intel Mac.

Comment: Referring to this github issue https://github.com/oracle/docker-images/issues/1814 and this comment https://github.com/oracle/docker-images/issues/1814#issuecomment-826554712 about parallels for virtual machines on M1 chips.

Comment: Oracle database is only supported on Intel/AMD processors (no ARM) and only on RedHat based Linux flavors or Windows. Technically also on Solaris running on SPARC, but that doesn't apply for most people... It isn't supported on Ubuntu or any Debian Linux or Mac OS - the OS kernel is too different. Given that Packed has steadily reduced the number of operating systems and chip architectures that it supports over the last 20 years, that is unlikely to change.

Comment: @pmdba Granted the OP's problem is the M1 Chip, note that this is Docker we're talking about, not plain macOS, so it does work perfectly on it, since the image is built on top of Oracle Linux 7, I've run at least 3 or 4 different Oracle Database containers on my Mac, without any problem (also set up a Dataguard to test its limit and it worked flawlessly), you can have a look at their official GitHub repo here : https://github.com/oracle/docker-images/tree/main/OracleDatabase

Comment: @EdwardKirk but did you also run this on docker in M1. I also tried the above repository. tried to build an oracle image and it failed. I got the same issue as mentioned here https://github.com/oracle/docker-images/issues/1814

Comment: Docker pulls kernel libraries from the underlying host OS. Oracle on Docker docs (https://github.com/oracle/docker-images/tree/main/OracleDatabase/SingleInstance) states: "Oracle Database ... is supported for Oracle Linux 7 and Red Hat Enterprise Linux (RHEL) 7. ... see My Oracle Support note: ... (Doc ID 2216342.1)" The Doc ID states that the Oracle binaries in their Docker image are built/certified for Oracle Linux 7 hosts only, and will also run on RedHat 7. They're not supported on Mac OS, Ubuntu, or any other *NIX flavors; even if you do get them to work - the results will not be stable.

Comment: Also note that the Docker issue you linked to was referencing an Oracle Linux host using an ARM processor, not Mac OS.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

## Oracle Database on M1 Mac

This is a doozy.. Oracle Database isn't supported on MacOS, however, with Docker virtualizing linux, it can be. Unfortunately, even though Docker supports M1 Mac ARM virtualization, Oracle Database relies heavily on some low level kernel calls that Docker and Rosetta 2 can't handle. This leads us to the only possible solution to run locally: Using full emulation (a virtual machine).

1. Install [Lima](https://github.com/lima-vm/lima) with [HomeBrew](https://brew.sh/). Lima is a sort of unofficial "macOS subsystem for Linux" with support for running VMs with different architecture (like running an x86 OS on top of ARM MacOS):

```sh
brew install lima
```

2. Create a new Impish Ubuntu (default) Virtual Machine:

```sh
limactl start
```

3. Select **Open an editor to override the configuration**.
4. Using the default editor (vi) modify the **arch** field to the following (`i` to enter insert mode, make the change, `ESC` to enter command mode, `:wq` to exit and save).

```yaml
arch: "x86_64"
```

5. Run the newly created default Lima VM, and change directories to the new VM's home directory. (All commands past this should be run in the newly started shell unless specified otherwise).

```sh
lima
cd ~
```

6. Install [Docker for Ubuntu](https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/ubuntu/) in the Lima VM.
7. Add your user to the docker group, and activate the changes to be able to run docker commands without root access:

```sh
sudo usermod -aG docker $USER
newgrp docker
```

8. Run Image from docker hub

```sh
docker login
docker run -d -p 1521:1521 --name oracle store/oracle/database-enterprise:12.2.0.1
```

9. Connect with default values

```sh
username/password@SID: sys/Oradoc_db1@ORCLCDB
```

Comment: What I don't understand, supposedly Docker on M1 supports running Intel containers in full emulation mode (also using qemu) directly (--platform linux/amd64), so why is the lima step necessary?

Comment: This did worked, thank you. Only thing I changed was that instead of building the image I used the official image https://hub.docker.com/_/oracle-database-enterprise-edition with developer tier. All I had to do was to `docker login` before I could run the image.

Comment: Not woking for me on m1

Comment: @RodFerreira What's not working about it? I'm on a 2020 M1 Macbook Pro.

Comment: @ryoka There is an open issue on Lima's github with exactly the same problem I had. https://github.com/lima-vm/lima/issues/713

Comment: Could try using an older version of Lima without the qemu issue

Comment: @marc.guenther - I'm right there with you.  Seems like this should be working the same with just `docker` since it runs through a virtual machine.

Answer (score 12):

If someone is still struggling with this one, I found a better and straight forward solution:

1. Install [Homebrew](https://brew.sh/)
2. Install Colima

```
brew install colima
```

3. Install Docker

```
brew install docker
```

4. Start Colima by setting up x86_64 architecture

```
colima start --memory 8 --arch x86_64
```

5. Test Docker

```
docker run hello-world
```

Note: You should clean everything related to docker from your system along with docker desktop, with this you do not need docker desktop

Comment: This worked really nicely and was much more simple than anything else suggested.

Comment: I am still not able to run docker-compose tried to install it separately with brew install docker-compose, but still no luck. Do you know how to use docker compose with this method?

Comment: How weird, after I did a docker run the docker compose command started to work.

Comment: Thank you, it worked out for me also. It would be great if you could provide more information about your answer.

Comment: I wrote the original accepted answer, but looks like Colima is now by far the better solution.. Would be nice if this could be moved as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 4):

I used Colima on my m2 Macbook air and it works perfectly

```bash
brew install colima
brew install docker
colima start --memory 4 --arch x86_64
docker run -e ORACLE_PASSWORD=pass -p 1521:1521 -d gvenzl/oracle-xe
```

Answer (score 3):

If you can use Oracle 19c there is now an ARM native version.

You can download it here: https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/oracle19c-linux-arm64-downloads.html

You can find instructions for building a docker image here: https://github.com/oracle/docker-images/tree/main/OracleDatabase/SingleInstance

Comment: Wow this is actually a very simple solution and one that works with 19c. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

After investing some time on it, here is what I tested and worked and didn't work for me.

- Lima - For me it didn't work.
  From what I got, Lima is a qemu wrapper. So in theory it should work, but I had same problems as the ones described on this open issue:
  https://github.com/lima-vm/lima/issues/713#issuecomment-1064151675
- Multipass - Didn't work.
  Multipass is an Ubuntu's vm. The problem is that it does not support cross architecture for now. You will only be able to create vms for the same architecture (aarch64) and oracle won't run on it.
- Qemu directly.
  This is the only option that worked for me, if you are interested on the steps here it is:

1. `brew install qemu utm`

obs.: utm is a graphical tool to run qemu without having to know its complicated commands.

2. Download an amd64 linux iso of your preference.

In my case it was an ubuntu server (just make sure it is for amd64)

3. On utm create a new emulator and select the image you downloaded

I've selected for the machine architecture the first one available (label with 2009), there is one tagged with a (default) but it is too slow - avoid this one.

2 cores for cpu, 4G mem was enough for me.

For the shared folder, it is not a very straight forward the way to access it, so in the end scp was enough for file transfer between host/guest machines.

4. Once you have passed the installation process and have logged in, install docker:

https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/ubuntu/

extra: `sudo apt-get install docker-compose`

5. Load your oracle docker image and run it.

If you have any volume configured you need to remember to give access permission to it (chmod)

6. Enjoy :)

Answer (score 1):

To build and run the [Oracle-19c-EE-Container for ARM64](https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/oracle19c-linux-arm64-downloads.html) on macOS follow the [Linux ARM64 instructions](https://github.com/oracle/docker-images/tree/main/OracleDatabase/SingleInstance):

```
% ./buildContainerImage.sh -v 19.3.0 -e
--> oracle/database:19.3.0-ee
Build completed in 207 seconds.
```

Answer (score 1):

### Using the arm64 Linux image of Oracle Database Enterprise Edition on docker on macOS

- install docker: `brew install --cask docker` **or** download it from the website: https://docs.docker.com/get-docker/

  - Remember to start docker and the container whenever you restart your computer.
- Login to Oracle's registry: `docker login container-registry.oracle.com`

  - Get your token from https://container-registry.oracle.com/. Click Top right > Auth token
  - Accept license on https://container-registry.oracle.com/ords/ocr/ba/database/enterprise (see screenshot). See https://stackoverflow.com/a/47887936/7365866 for more information.
  - Enter your email and the token
- Run Oracle in a container: `docker run -d -e ORACLE_PWD=password -p 1521:1521 -p 5500:5500 --name my-oracle-db container-registry.oracle.com/database/enterprise:19.19.0.0`. This uses [Oracle Database Server Release Docker Image Documentation](https://container-registry.oracle.com/ords/ocr/ba/database/enterprise)

  - I specifically chose `19.19.0.0` because that has a `arm64` image, which supports ARM macs.
  - I specifically set a password to avoid complexity and bugs related to the randomly generated password. The password is simple (`password`), and is only for local development.
  - To see logs, run `docker logs my-oracle-db`

    - to watch the logs, run `docker logs my-oracle-db -f`
- install Oracle SQL Developer for your machine: https://www.oracle.com/database/sqldeveloper/technologies/download/

  - This involves downloading a zip file containing `SQLDeveloper.app`.
  - Use Google Chrome, and keep trying many times. Warning: It often doesn't work, so keep clicking buttons (Bad gateway error).
- Open Oracle SQL Developer and connect to database with correct configuration.

  - Optional: name: `my-oracle-db`
  - Username: `SYSTEM`
  - password: `password`
  - hostname: `localhost`
  - port: `1521`
  - SID: `ORCLCDB`

Comment: Wow, you saved my day, many thanks! I'd just add one more thing—starting the container takes around 20 minutes, OMG :D.

Comment: Yea lol, I remember 20 minutes on a macbook pro with M1 pro chip ️

Answer (score 0):

Here is worked for me:

1. You cannot change the CDB name
2. It is hardwired to use a domain name
3. The password must mixed-case 8 characters or more with a special character

```
docker run -d --name 12c \
--privileged \
--memory=4096M \
-p 1512:1521/tcp -p 5512:5500/tcp \
-e DB_SID=ORCLCDB \
-e DB_PDB=ORCLPDB \
-e DB_DOMAIN=localdomain \
-e DB_PASSWD=Password@2 \
-v ${HOME}/containers/storage/oracle/EE12201/u02/app/oracle:/ORCL/u02/app/oracle \
-v ${HOME}/containers/storage/oracle/EE12201/u03/app/oracle:/ORCL/u03/app/oracle \
-v ${HOME}/containers/storage/oracle/EE12201/u04/app/oracle:/ORCL/u04/app/oracle \
container-registry.oracle.com/database/enterprise:12.2.0.1
```

Comment: I have found a simple solution 

# simple solution
https://oralytics.com/2022/09/22/running-oracle-database-on-docker-on-apple-m1-chip/

Answer (score -2):

There are two issues here:

1. Oracle Database is not supported on ARM processors, only Intel. See here: https://github.com/oracle/docker-images/issues/1814
2. Oracle Database Docker images are only supported with Oracle Linux 7 or Red Hat Enterprise Linux 7 as the host OS. See here: https://github.com/oracle/docker-images/tree/main/OracleDatabase/SingleInstance

> Oracle Database ... is supported for Oracle Linux 7 and Red Hat Enterprise Linux (RHEL) 7. For more details please see My Oracle Support note: **Oracle Support for Database Running on Docker (Doc ID 2216342.1)**

The referenced My Oracle Support Doc ID goes on to say that the database binaries in their Docker image are built specifically for Oracle Linux hosts, and will also work on Red Hat. That's it.

Because Docker provides *process level* virtualization it still pulls kernel and other OS libraries from the underlying host OS. A Docker image built for Oracle Linux *needs* an Oracle Linux host; it doesn't bring the Oracle Linux OS with it. Only Oracle Linux or Red Hat Linux are supported for *any* Oracle database Linux installation, with or without Docker. Ubuntu, Mac OS, Debian, or any other *NIX flavor will not provide predictable reliable results, even if it is hacked into working or the processes appear to work normally.

Comment: My personal experience is that the oracle docker image works fine on Ubuntu .. I use it and rely on it for development everyday, without needing any special hacks to get it running.

Comment: The fact that it is not supported means that even if it _appears_ to work, results are not certified or guaranteed; it cannot be trusted. For example, internal mathematical or cryptographic functions could return incorrect results and you wouldn't notice; any variety of features could misbehave at any time; some storage architectures require directly loading kernel modules. _Any_ problem you would ever have would leave you without recourse or anything other than anecdotal help, as the first and only thing Oracle will tell you is that you _must_ reproduce the problem on a supported environment.

Comment: The only thing you can say about _any_ unsupported configuration is that it _might_ work, _most_ of the time. Given how easy it is to set up an actual supported environment, why wouldn't you?

Comment: Nah, I am letting anyone that reads what you posted above know, that from daily experience, I can say it works just fine with no problems.  Choosing whether or not to run RHEL or Oracle Linux  is not about how easy it is, there is much more that comes into the decision that whether you can run an Oracle docker.  I think your original answer was misleading, and not really that helpful.  I am not suggesting running a production oracle db on ubuntu:  but OP was asking about running it on a Mac: so obviously we are talking about a dev environment.

Comment: In my experience in commercial software development and in-house development, you can't certify your product as working on a particular platform if you haven't built and tested everything on a certified/supported version of that platform. Otherwise all you can say is that it _appears_ to work as intended, but isn't guaranteed (you can't promise what the platform vendor won't promise). That isn't enough for commercial development _or_ in-house/enterprise development. In 30 years I've never had an employer or customer that would accept that.

Comment: Have you ever tried to run an oracle docker image on ubuntu, and if so tested it?

Comment: While it may _appear_ to work, that doesn't make it fit for development or testing because it can only ever _appear_ to work correctly. There is no _guarantee_ that it is working correctly, or will continue to do so. If the platform vendor won't make that promise to you, then you can't make any promises to your customer.

Comment: I run my dev environment in Arch (previously Ubuntu) without issue also. We use Centos in CI to ensure that things work as expected and our QA/staging environments use the exact same operating system and environment that our production environment does.

Comment: So if it isn't about ease of implementation - as claimed by Drew - what _is_ the reason that people choose unsupported architectures for their development environments? I tried to research this and found lots of "how to" guides, but couldn't find a single article or blog post that even attempted to justify _why_ anyone would want to do it in the first place. My personal experience has always been that no customer or employer would have allowed to begin with, so why is this such a big deal? We can't claim "it works just fine" because Oracle clearly doesn't promise that.